# Wordpress / ACF field as an admin column

Tags: php, wordpress, field, advanced-custom-fields

I've created an acf field named 'cislo_ponuky'. It's numeric.

What I need now is to display it as an admin column in a custom post type called Nehnutelnosti owning a slug of 'nehnutelnosti'.

```
add_action( 'manage_nehnutelnosti_custom_column' , 'custom_mycpt_column', 10, 2 );
```

function custom_mycpt_column( $column, $post_id ) {
  switch ( $column ) {

```
// display the value of an ACF (Advanced Custom Fields) field
case 'acf_field' :
  echo get_field( 'cislo_ponuky', $post_id );  
  break;
```

}
}

This code's not working for me unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

you can use "codepress-admin-columns" plugin for admin column  https://wordpress.org/plugins/codepress-admin-columns/

Comment: No I can't I tried'. Working with ACF is allowed only in a premium version. I need a free solution.